# How do I remove ufw blocked protocol 59 log noise?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ufw

The logfile on one of my private servers running Ubuntu 14.04 is being filled with messages of the following form:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=[macaddr] SRC=[srcipv6addr] DST=[destipv6addr] LEN=40 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=16 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=59
```

According to `/etc/procotols`, protocol 59 is `ipv6-nonxt`. I've added the following line to `/etc/ufw/before6.rules`

```
-A ufw6-before-input -p ipv6-nonxt -j ACCEPT
```

and reloaded the firewall rules with `sudo ufw reload`, but the noise continues. I've verified the rule is being applied to iptables as follows:

```
$ sudo ip6tables --list | grep nxt
ACCEPT     ipv6-nonxt    anywhere             anywhere
```

How do I prevent my log files from being filled with this noise?